# What determines which screen the account control popup will appear on?

Tags: windows, user-account-control

I'm running a Windows 10 system with one touch screen, one normal screen and no mouse or keyboard. I need to run an application with administrator privileges.

I'm worried about which screen the Account Control popup will appear on - if it appears on the non-touch screen then users will have no way to allow the program to run.

I know that:

1. It runs on screen 2 on my development PC (with mouse and keyboard, no touch screen), regardless of whether screen 2 is on the left or right
2. It runs on the same screen regardless of whether the application was launched by a shortcut on the left or right screen.

I tried to google this, but the only things that came back were links on how to disable User Account Control, which we really don't want to do.

What is the logic that determines which screen the popup appears on?

[Edit for new things I have tried]

1. Unplugging screen 2, running the application, closing the application, plug screen 2 back in.
2. Dragging the UAC popup to screen 1, clicking details, changing UAC settings and returning them to the original state.

**[SOLVED]**
I figured it out (at least partially) but I can't mark it as answered for at least two days.

Basically, after unplugging and replugging screens the other way around, changing the primary display worked. This didn't work until after I did the plug/unplug, but there's no guarantee that was the thing that did it, since I'd tried a few other things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after physically unplugging and replugging monitors so that screen one became screen 2 and the reverse, switching which screen was the primary display works to control the popup now.

Changing the primary display didn't work before. But it does now. I have no idea why - there's no guarantee that it was to do with switching them around.

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect it to pop up by default on the primary display, but remember its last position. This would appear to be confirmed by [TechNet: UAC Prompt displays on 2nd monitor only RRS feed](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dcdba280-7626-4ff1-9b83-c262d298380c/uac-prompt-displays-on-2nd-monitor-only?forum=win10itprogeneral):

> escknx:
>
> Regardless of what I try, UAC prompts display only on 2nd monitor, while everything else works fine on primary monitor.

> Stereoman:
>
> drag the UAC Prompt to your Primary Monitor and click show more details on the prompt then click change when these notifications appear, another UAC window will open up with a vertical bar with 4 different settings, just drag the bar setting down and then back up to it's original setting position then click ok, this will re trigger UAC's screen position to your primary monitor.

So: upon deployment, make sure the touch screen is your primary display, and position the UAC popup there if it isn't.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but dragging to the other monitor didn't work for me. I just tried dragging the popup from screen 2 to 1 one and accepting. Then I closed and ran again. Appeared on screen 2 again. I will check the primary monitor on install thing again. I may have to unplug some screens.

Comment: See the second quote which suggests modifying the settings while the popup is open.

Comment: Yep, tried that, but it didn't help. I think I've solved it now - after fiddling with plugs, just changing the primary display works. THIS DIDN'T WORK BEFORE. Windows. Gotta love it. We will work out a deployment routine that gets it right in production. 

Thanks for the help though.